# What should be $\alpha$ for confidence interval with length of $2$?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

> For $n=20$ samples of normal distribution with variance $10$, what should be $\alpha$, so the length of the confidence interval will be exactly $2$?

So the calculation is:

$$2=2z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}=2z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{20}}=2z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\\z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}=\sqrt{2} $$

BUT! There's a problem - $\sqrt 2 > 1$

Why is it happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I think you may be confusing $z$-values with probabilities. What's the problem with having it $>1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $z$-value can be greater than $1$ - you're confusing them with probabilities. You need to look in [the $z$-table](https://www.google.ie/search?q=z%20values&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLh-bnis7RAhViL8AKHbtPDxYQ_AUICCgB&biw=1680&bih=940#imgrc=n_wEBM8lL0N6nM%3A) and find a corresponding choice of $\alpha$ for $\sqrt{2} \approx 1.41$ and set that to $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}$.

Comment: but $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ represents an area under the distribution graph, so how can it be equal to $\sqrt 2$?

Comment: Incorrect, I'm afraid - you need to revise $z$-scores: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score

Comment: Okay... got it! ty